# Android CPU-GPU parallelization and eglSwapBuffers

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es-2.0

I have an android app using OpenGL ES 2.0 and frame times look like this:

[image]

As you can see after onDrawFrame (CPU frame simulation and GL commands issuing), the eglSwapBuffers instruction takes a lot of time. I is my understanding that issued gl commands are actually executed by the CPU at that point, before actually swapping the buffers.

My question / observation is: doesn't this mechanism break the CPU / GPU parallelization, since the CPU is waiting for the GPU to finish? shouldn't I be able to start processing the next frame without having to finish for eglSwapBuffers?

Comment: CPU thread wait for the GPU to complete the tasks, as there is nothing to do until the next frame is ready for rendering. CPU running more cycles than GPU does not help much in most games. And game calculations are good to be calculated just before rendering the next frame.